# This insert pic code works on Excel Windows but not Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I don't know if it was working on Mac before but I want it to work on both

The code insert pics and resize them to match the cells

it works flawlessly on windows on the same shared file on OneDrive

also tested offline version of the file on my Mac and on new file with MAcro enabled .. tested  also other codes and they work perfectly like auto Uppercase .. etc

can you help me figure out what's the problem?

```
    Sub InsertPictures()
Dim PicList() As Variant
Dim PicFormat As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim sShape As Shape
On Error Resume Next
PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
 
xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
xRowIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Row
 
If IsArray(PicList) Then
 
For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
xColIndex = xColIndex + 1
If xColIndex = 11 Then GoTo Continue1 Else GoTo Continue2
 
Continue1:
xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 1
xColIndex = xColIndex - 10
 
Continue2:
Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "not working" is not a great description of what happens when you try to run that.

Comment: I can select only one pic from my desktop and after clicking ok nothing happens ..

Comment: See here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac015.htm

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I'm not a high level of an expert on VBA I can barely edit them
Also don't have the time to think it and do it .. I have a deadline .. but I will read it later and try .. now I'll wait for someone who can modify it for me and save me from looking for a windows machine.